# Unable to install Windows 10 - 0xc000098

Tags: windows-10, installation

I'm currently trying to install Windows 10 on my device and I've downloaded the ISO file. After burning the file to my USB device, I've tried running it but I’ve kept getting these codes.

0xc0000098 - tm.sys (It is either corrupted or missing).

I've tried many times burning the ISO into the USB, even redownloading it and checking the Md5 but still getting the error.
**Is there anyway I can fix the problem?**

Comment: Go through this : http://www.prime-expert.com/articles/b18/fix-0xC0000098-windows-bcd-does-not-contain-valid-os-entry.php

Answer (score 0):

Check your usb device for malfuction.

Check the integrity of the of Windows 10 ISO.

Try using the official Windows 10 tool, or use the app "Rufus"

Comment: Did all that, usb is fine. Windows 10 ISO md5 is the same, using both apps to burn the file

Comment: Check if you bios  is set as UEFI, or regular boot.

Comment: UEFI I think...

Comment: If your computer is UEFI based, these are normally systems that come pre-loaded with Windows 8 or later, you will need to prepare the ISO file for such a configuration or you will receive an error message during setup. The thumbdrive needs to be formatted as FAT32 and use the GPT partitioning scheme. To do this, you need to use Rufus.

Comment: I did use rufus with those configs but still got the same error

Comment: -Select GPT partitioning for EUFI firmware as the Partition scheme
-Choose FAT32 NOT NTFS as the File system
-Make sure your USB thumbdrive in the Device list box

Comment: If this isn't working you can switch to normal boot. Probably will start the setup.

Comment: How to switch to normal boot? Using HP Pavillion 14

Comment: In HP usually is F1 or F10 on the boot logo, this config should be done in the BIOS.